# fotorama how to work with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fotorama

I got two problems by using ajax in fotorama

i) before ajax, my code is:

```
<div id="AjaxPhoto" class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-ratio="4/3"></div>
```

after ajax, my code is:

```
<div id="AjaxPhoto" class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-ratio="4/3">
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.jpg" />
</div>
```

the fotorama may work or not work in this case

ii) assume the fotorama works 'successfully', when I clear data by

```
$("#AjaxPhoto").empty();
$(".fotorama--hidden").remove();
```

and then add the other images, the fotorama is exactly not work again. Does fotorama support ajax?

Comment: Please clearly explain the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you clear the photos & re-add the photos you need to re-initalize the plugin again for it to work.

```
$("#AjaxPhoto").empty();
$(".fotorama--hidden").remove();
// Load the new set of Photos here
// after that the below statement will re-initialize the fotorama gallery plugin
$('.fotorama').fotorama();
```

Comment: $("#AjaxPhoto").data('fotorama').destroy();
$("#AjaxPhoto").empty();
$('.fotorama').fotorama(); I try this but stil failure

Comment: please can you share the worked code, with us. thanks

Comment: @PoPo the above code is working. If you've any problem different than this, then post a Question I will surely try to help you.